# Integrating glassbox session event with another app

Tags: json, integration, splunk, dynatrace

Does anyone know how to integrate glassbox session events with splunk/ Dynatrace? By the way, there is no option to export glassbox session events alone but we can we see all the events in expert view section inside the session. Or else is there a way to export these events from glassbox session as json/text format? The first solution which I require is how to extract the events from a glassbox session. Thanks. Valid replies greatly appreciated.

I tried to find options available from a glassbox session to extract the events within the expert view but failed. There is a provision to export the session replay which will be downloaded in .gb format. I need a way to export the events within a glassbox session in json/text format.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.